# Pass object from view A to view B

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have constructed an object in view A. I intend to pass this object to view B and then print the parameters of the object in a label. Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to access the parameters of the object in view B. I'm getting the error "object does not contain a definition for 'hrs'"

Code in view A:

```
async void Calculate_btn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Calculation calc = new Calculation()
    {
        hrs = "qwe",
        cse = "rty",
        aqe = "uio"

    };



    var page = new Results(calc);
    await Navigation.PushModalAsync(page);
}
```

Code in view B:

```
public Results(object number)
{

    InitializeComponent();
    string hours = number.hrs;
    label.text = hours;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should change

```
public Results(object number)
```

to

```
public Results(Calculation number)
```